# Speaker protection using only zener diodes?

Tags: amplifier, voltage-regulator, speakers, circuit-protection, voltage-clipping

It is crucial to match amplifiers to speakers correctly and use them with care.  But in some cases you want extra protection from blowing up the speaker.  I have thought of a ridiculously simple idea - to use zener diodes parallel to the speaker.

- Zener diodes let through current only after certain voltage point (for example 5v) and by doing so they keep the voltage stable at that point. Zener diodes are mostly used as voltage regulators.

Not sure if it is wise to do so and how it will clip the sound when the diodes start letting through current of overvoltage but as I see it - it might clip the sound badly but it will still protect the speaker from too much voltage going in. I have found few circuits using this technique but descriptions are really lacking and I am not sure what to expect.

Sure, there are better options than using zener diodes as speaker protection circuit but for the sake of simplicity I am very interested if this would work as intented - protect speakers from over-voltage and power peaks.

My (simple) circuit design:

*Light diode acts as a clip indicator

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkUvI1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Similar circuit I have found online though it does not use any resistor in between them basically creating a 2ohm short for voltages over (in example) 5v.  Could anyone comment how would amplifier handle such circuit design?

[image]

Comment: Speakers can take massive overloads but not continuously. Music produces a big peak wattage but a small average wattage. Do you get where I'm coming from?

Comment: The added circuitry is going to add some stray capacitance to your speaker circuit and will affect how the speaker sounds.  I don't know know enough about zener diodes to tell you if it's going to be at all noticeable, but if you simulate this circuit make sure you're simulating the added capacitance.

Comment: @Adam  I dont quite get where is this capacitance coming from. Zener diodes pass current only after certain voltage point so they don't "work" when voltage is less than their specified point and should not affect how the speaker sounds

Comment: Check out [this datasheet](http://www.diodes.com/downloads/10295).  Your diode is going to add some capacitance to that circuit since diodes, like all electrical components, have a non-zero capacitance between the leads.

Comment: @Adam, don't be silly. A few tens or hundreds of pF in a speaker circuit aren't going to make the slightest bit of difference, except maybe by helping to suppress RFI.

Comment: That was I was about to say. The capacitance should reach up to 2uF to make any noticeable sound difference

Comment: Anyway, the point @Andyaka is making is perfectly valid. Music in general has a huge peak-to-average ratio. By limiting the peaks like that, you'll have to reduce the average level (the perceived loudness) to a ridiculously low value in order to avoid distortion (clipping). In other words, the sound level will be far too low, or it will sound terrible.

Comment: I wouldn't call it silly to suggest researching whether or not you're unintentionally adding a filter to your speaker circuit, but yes, a few hundred picofarads isn't going to make a difference in this application.

Comment: Andy is right, and, moreover, you'll put more stress on the *amp* by doing this. Because when the zeners start conducting, the [rather high] current through them will somehow have to be provided by the amp, in addition to the current it already provides to the speaker. So you'll protect your speakers but may overload your amp if it doesn't have the appropriate protections. Which one is the most expensive?

Comment: @dim I am aware that when the 'protection' kicks in the amp will have to provide power for that 5ohm resistor thats in between the diodes. I don't plan to push the amplifier into clipping - that's basically the whole point of doing this circuit.

Comment: Mmh, anyway, actually, I just realized that, with an ideal amp, the speakers aren't even really protected with your circuit since there is no resistor in series with the amp output. So it will just force the amp to provide more current than it should, but the voltage across the speaker will be the same as without your circuit. Now, if the amp has some overcurrent limit, it may work, but that is very ugly.

Comment: @dim I believe you are wrong. There is a resistor between zener diodes. It 'absorbs' all the voltage filtered from zener diodes and the voltage stays (i.e.) up to 5v but everything above it goes to the resistor. Don't take me wrong, but putting a resistor in series with a speaker seems rather stupid for this purpose to me. Correct me if I missed something - it's all about learning new thing after all :)

Comment: Yes, putting a resistor in series with the speaker would be stupid, for a load of reasons. But, really, I think I'm right. To work as a voltage regulator (or limiter), a zener needs to be put *after* a resistor in series with the supply. If you put the resistor in series with the zener, it is just useless. Look at your schematic: the speaker is still in parallel with the source. If you assume the source is perfect, the source voltage won't be lower at the speaker: there is nowhere to have a voltage drop. Now, of course, an amp is not a perfect source. But I'll maintain relying on that is ugly.

Comment: @dim You are 100% right. I really did forget that. I'll try to think of something and will update the schematic :)

Comment: You'll certainly find it is not that easy. As we agreed on, a resistor in series with the speaker would have too much bad effects. So you need some active device (transistor/mosfet) between the source and the speaker, that will be triggered on overvoltage. Transistor/mosfets have can't work easily with alternating currents, so you'll certainly need a couple of them to fix that. In the end, it will be complicated and introduce distortion...

Comment: Moreover, if, as you said earlier, "the whole point of doing this circuit is to prevent the amplifier going into clipping", you should maybe stop thinking about it. Clipping is *not* a problem for the amps. It is a problem for the *speakers*. And, with your circuit, you are basically making the speakers clip before the amp would clip them...